# Need text input to accept a space and the remainder of the field

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

How can I can alter this to get it to read the text before and after spaces? I need text2 to be able to have mulitple seperated words.  e.g.  'Veni Vidi' or even 'Veni Vidi Vici' instead of 'Venividi' or 'Venividivici'

string text2 = str1.Split('|')[1]

Would I replaced text2 with str3?

Reading input from a .txt file

```
{
        this.accounts = Enumerable.ToList<string>((IEnumerable<string>) System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("accounts.txt"));
        foreach (string str1 in this.accounts)
        {
          string text1 = str1.Split('|')[0];
          string text2 = str1.Split('|')[1];
          string str2 = str1.Split('|')[2];
          string text3 = str1.Split('|')[3];
```

Comment: You are splitting line by `|` not by space, so if you have `Veni Vidi` line you will get `Veni Vidi`

Comment: At first line you get a string array populated from file. Then you process lines one by one. So if a line from file equals to `1|Veni Vidi|str2|text3` text2 will be equal to `Veni Vidi`.